# Find element within another element object with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form object passed to a function.

Inside this function I want to access the form object itself and find an input within that form object.

```
var myinput = $(form, '#MyId');
```

did not help.

Comment: If you have an ID on the element, just use that...

Comment: @tymeJV You should have left that as an answer :)

Comment: Whats wrong with `$("#myID")`? just use it

Comment: What's wrong with it is that it will search globally and not just within the form object itself.

Comment: @Chris - IDs are unique, so what difference will that make?

Comment: @tymeJV That would work if the form DOM element is in the same document (it can be in a fragment as well, or a different document), as ids should be unique. But it is not sure that is the case here.

Comment: @j08691: Very true in this case. I still don't think that is the most useful answer though since it may be that the selector given is not the actual one, etc. There may also be efficiency things due to searching less stuff but I suspect probably not if you are selecting IDs.

Comment: @j08691 The function receives a form element as a parameter. We cannot be sure it is a part of the current DOM document. It would be a mistake to rely on that.

Comment: @j08691 It will take much longer to search a whole document instead of a form-object.

Comment: @HelloWorld - No, you're talking femtoseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You've got it the wrong way round. Try:

```
var myinput = $('#MyId', form);
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/find/). It is much more effective than trying random stuff.

```
var myinput = $(form).find('#MyId'); //or equivalently
var myinput = $('#MyId', form);
```

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-elements-when-i-already-have-a-dom-element/ just found this!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will give you the value of particular Id given as shown in the code

```
$('#MyId',form).val();
```